# Importing class is not working between files after transpilation with TS

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tsc

I am getting a runtime error - after transpilation with TS.

I am getting this error:

```
/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/live-mutex/dist/rw-client.js:23
class RWLockClient extends client_1.Client {
                                    ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/live-mutex/dist/rw-client.js:23:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
```

Here is the file that is causing the error when it's loaded:

```
'use strict';
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const assert = require("assert");
const client_1 = require("./client");
const index_1 = require("./index");
const shared_internal_2 = require("./shared-internal");
class RWLockClient extends client_1.Client {  //// <<<<<<< !! here is where the error occurs
   // ...
}
```

and the above file is loading this one (client.js):

```
'use strict';
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const util = require("util");
const assert = require("assert");
const net = require("net");
const UUID = require("uuid");
const chalk_1 = require("chalk");
const json_parser_1 = require("./json-parser");
const shared_internal_1 = require("./shared-internal");
class Client {
   // ...
}

exports.Client = Client;
```

does anyone see the problem? I cannot figure it out. The tsconfig I am using I have been using for a long time, so I doubt it's that but let me know if that info would help.

Comment: What file is the first one? Looks like some kind of circular dependency.

Comment: yeah I think you are right